# Backup an iPod Nano 4th generation?

Tags: backup, sync, ipod

I have an [iPod Nano 4G](http://www.ifixit.com/Device/iPod_Nano_4th_Generation) and it is slowly dying on me. I would thus like to make a backup of its user data contents (so as to drop them later on onto a [SanDisk Sansa Clip Zip](http://mp3players.productwiki.com/sandisk-sansa-clip-zip/)).

Can I do it from within Ubuntu?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the iPods store mp3 files which are completely jumbled but have intact ID3 tags, which is all that really matters. Can you mount it? Do you get any useful output if you run something like `find /media/ipod | grep mp3`?

Comment: It seems that `gtkpod` allows an easy way to do this, keeping intact the filenames (or re-recreating them). See posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this rather outdated guide: [How To Backup Your iPod Music on Linux](http://www.foogazi.com/2008/03/27/how-to-backup-your-ipod-music-on-linux/), I used `gtkpod 2.1.1` in Ubuntu `12.04` to export all the music files from the iPod to a backup folder.

I had to:

- Connect the iPod USB cable
- Mount the iPod `device` in Thunar (using its left pane)
- Open `gtkpod`, then select the iPod, then `right-click` in the `Playlist Tracks` pane, then `Select All`
- Either `Tools > Export Tracks > To Filesystem` or `right-click > Copy > To Filesystem`
- Choose an `Export Destination Directory`, hit `Save`
- Sit back and relax while the backup is being completed

You can check if all went well by looking at the `number` of files in the destination dir and the `size` of the files contained as displayed in the `Thunar status bar`, and cross-checking this with `View > Repository information` in `gtkpod`. I had a discrepancy of 11 items (1599 on the iPod vs 1588 in the backup dir) but, oh well, maybe there were some duplicates lying around.

See also:

- [Exporting files from the iPod](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/Advanced_features) (official docs)